# I can't return an object value, but it is showed up by console.log

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-pipe

I'm trying to return a string value of an object generated by aws translate, the structure's object is

```
{
 TranslatedText: "Hola", 
 SourceLanguageCode: "en", 
 TargetLanguageCode: "es"
}
```

the function

```
    this.translate.translator.translateText(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack)
        return err.stack;
      } 
      if(data) { 
        console.log("translation :");
        console.log(data.TranslatedText);
        return data.TranslatedText;
      }
    });
```

I can see the string in console, but it is not returning it.

I think that I'm misunderstanding some async job here, and maybe the returned value is actually getting an undefined, but I'm not clear.

Answer (score 0):

As it is in a callback function, so you won't be able to return the data like the way you are doing. Try using promises instead.

Answer (score 0):

If doesn't make sense to return values from callbacks. Do what you want to do with the return value inside your callback.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `translateText` is an `async` function. Therefore, await it like so:

```
this.translate.translator.translateText(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack)
        return err.stack;
      } 
      if(data) { 
        console.log("translation :");
        console.log(data.TranslatedText);
        return data.TranslatedText;
      }
    });
```